# "Got an error reading communication packets" when connecting to Google Cloud SQL from Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I connect to Google Cloud SQL from Firebase Functions using whitelisted public IP. It worked until yesterday. I now get the following error:

> {  insertId: 
>   "s=cd0e3771777e45499a64e5d27f181595;i=41f0f9;b=c506ddb142564223b97b8eae98860618;m=154ecd3c3d6;t=57b6a4c27df31;x=1fb3c8162344104e-0@a1"
>   logName: 
>   "projects/[my-project]/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql.err"
>   receiveTimestamp:  "2018-11-24T14:56:04.390263054Z"    resource: {
>   labels: {    database_id:  "[my-project]:[my-db]"        project_id: 
>   "[my-project]"        region:  "asia"       }   type: 
>   "cloudsql_database"     }  severity:  "ERROR"    textPayload: 
>   "2018-11-24T14:55:57.984322Z 246208 [Note] Aborted connection 246208
>   to db: '[db-name]' user: '[db-user]' host: '107.178.237.15' (Got an
>   error reading communication packets)"    timestamp: 
>   "2018-11-24T14:55:57.984561Z"   }

The DB instance is fine. I can connect from my laptop as well as from GCE instance, just not Firebase Functions. But it used to work. Is there a way to get a more descriptive error message?